# Search and dispaly in next page using Ajax and Codeigniter with pagination and then filter search and display results inside a single div

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

While clicking on search button i want to display results in the next page with different header and content using ajax.

I want to display results inside

```
      <div id="printdiv">

      </div>
```

the results should be with pagination.

Then Using Checkbox filter I want to display results inside the same

```
     <div id="printdiv">

    </div>
```

The problem is pagination not working with different queries and on page loading it does not shows records.

What procedure should be the effective method to search and filter display results on next page with pagination using codeigniter and ajax.

Comment: you want to implement codeigniter pagination with ajax, right? You have the grid on the page, right? If yes then I can setup a demo for you.

Comment: I want to implement like walmart search and filter checkbox

Comment: I want to implement like this...

Comment: http://demos.mostlikers.com/CodeIgniter/content

Comment: The difference is clicking on a button loading content using ajax onload and then display by checking checkbox